# Using elasticsearch 6 to filter an array of objects in a document removing unmatched objects

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

In elasticsearch 6.0, I have created an index with a nested mapping type:

```
PUT node2
{
    "settings" : {
        "index" : {
            "number_of_shards" : 3,
            "number_of_replicas" : 0,
            "mapping.total_fields.limit" : "2300"
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
      "content": {
        "properties": {
          "basicPageBodyParagraphs": {
            "type": "nested"
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Where `basicPageBodyParagraphs` is an Array of Objects. A document in this index will look something like:

```json
{
  "id": "16dfb723-dac7-47cd-a898-47d9bd054c09",
  "fields": null,
  "more": null,
  "pathAlias": "about/sdc-access-test-2",
  "status": 0,
  "basicPageBodyParagraphs": [
    {
      "fabTextContent": "<p>This is a full text paragraph. The page is restricted to students. This paragraph has no further restrictions, so should be visible to all students.</p>",
      "paragraphAccessRoles": [],
      "type": "fab-text"
    },
    {
      "fabTextContent": "<p>This is a second full text paragraph. This one is restricted to students studying Biology.</p>",
      "paragraphAccessRoles": ["155eccdf-5ea0-ec11-8135-00155dfb7c0d"],
      "type": "fab-text"
    },
    {
      "type": "bullets",
      "items": [
        {
          "content": "<p>This is the first bullet point.</p>"
        },
        {
          "content": "<p>This is the second bullet point.</p>"
        }
      ],
      "title": "This is a bullets paragraph with access restrictions",
      "alignment": "left",
      "paragraphAccessRoles": ["4efd1649-ba34-eb11-810c-005056930a83"]
    }
  ],
  "contentType": "basic_page"
}
```

I want to be able to query my index and retrieve `basicPageBodyParagraphs` based on the `paragraphAccessRoles`, so if a student had an ID of **155eccdf-5ea0-ec11-8135-00155dfb7c0d** the query would return the document containing only:

```
"basicPageBodyParagraphs": [
    {
      "fabTextContent": "<p>This is a full text paragraph. The page is restricted to students. This paragraph has no further restrictions, so should be visible to all students.</p>",
      "paragraphAccessRoles": [],
      "type": "fab-text"
    },
    {
      "fabTextContent": "<p>This is a second full text paragraph. This one is restricted to students studying Biology.</p>",
      "paragraphAccessRoles": ["155eccdf-5ea0-ec11-8135-00155dfb7c0d"],
      "type": "fab-text"
    }
]
```

So that the first paragraph which contains no `paragraphAccessRoles` is returned, and the second with an `paragraphAccessRoles` matching the students ID is returned, but the 3rd, is not returned as the `paragraphAccessRoles` does not match the students ID (**155eccdf-5ea0-ec11-8135-00155dfb7c0d**).

For this, I am using the query:

```
POST /node2/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "pathAlias.keyword": "about/sdc-access-test-2"
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "basicPageBodyParagraphs",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "should": [
                  {
                    "terms": {
                      "basicPageBodyParagraphs.paragraphAccessRoles.keyword": [
                        "155eccdf-5ea0-ec11-8135-00155dfb7c0d"
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "bool": {
                      "must_not": [
                        {
                          "exists": {
                            "field": "basicPageBodyParagraphs.paragraphAccessRoles"
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            "inner_hits": {}
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This query partly returns what I want:

```json
{
  "took": 2,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 3,
    "successful": 3,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 7.4361506,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "node2",
        "_type": "content",
        "_id": "16dfb723-dac7-47cd-a898-47d9bd054c09",
        "_score": 7.4361506,
        "_source": {
          "id": "16dfb723-dac7-47cd-a898-47d9bd054c09",
          "fields": null,
          "more": null,
          "pathAlias": "about/sdc-access-test-2",
          "status": 0,
          "basicPageBodyParagraphs": [
            {
              "fabTextContent": "<p>This is a full text paragraph. The page is restricted to students. This paragraph has no further restrictions, so should be visible to all students.</p>",
              "paragraphAccessRoles": [],
              "type": "fab-text"
            },
            {
              "fabTextContent": "<p>This is a second full text paragraph. This one is restricted to students studying Biology.</p>",
              "paragraphAccessRoles": ["155eccdf-5ea0-ec11-8135-00155dfb7c0d"],
              "type": "fab-text"
            },
            {
              "type": "bullets",
              "items": [
                {
                  "content": "<p>This is the first bullet point.</p>"
                },
                {
                  "content": "<p>This is the second bullet point.</p>"
                }
              ],
              "title": "This is a bullets paragraph with access restrictions",
              "alignment": "left",
              "paragraphAccessRoles": ["4efd1649-ba34-eb11-810c-005056930a83"]
            }
          ],
          "contentType": "basic_page"
        },
        "inner_hits": {
          "basicPageBodyParagraphs": {
            "hits": {
              "total": 2,
              "max_score": 1,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_nested": {
                    "field": "basicPageBodyParagraphs",
                    "offset": 1
                  },
                  "_score": 1,
                  "_source": {
                    "fabTextContent": "<p>This is a second full text paragraph. This one is restricted to students studying Biology.</p>",
                    "paragraphAccessRoles": [
                      "155eccdf-5ea0-ec11-8135-00155dfb7c0d"
                    ],
                    "type": "fab-text"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "_nested": {
                    "field": "basicPageBodyParagraphs",
                    "offset": 0
                  },
                  "_score": 1,
                  "_source": {
                    "fabTextContent": "<p>This is a full text paragraph. The page is restricted to students. This paragraph has no further restrictions, so should be visible to all students.</p>",
                    "paragraphAccessRoles": [],
                    "type": "fab-text"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The document is returned, but the `basicPageBodyParagraphs` contains all 3 objects, rather than the 2 i expect.  It's not until you see further down that the returned data includes a `inner_hits` property which contains the 2 expected paragraphs (though not in order, from 0...1).  I would prefer not to bring back the results in a property outside of the document and instead have query remove the unmatched `basicPageBodyParagraphs` objects within the main document.

Is there a way to have the query filter out the unmatched `basicPageBodyParagraphs` and return those in the main document result?

Answer (score 0):

I don't this will work because of how [arrays of objects are flattened out](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html#nested-arrays-flattening-objects). I haven't seen this with `flattened` either and I'm skeptical if that would work.

But my first idea would try to go with parent-child. This will have a performance overhead and your queries will be more complicated but I'm not sure there is another way.